# Connections shows up in tcpdump but cannot not in auditd or ss

Tags: networking, socket, tcpdump, auditd

I ran `tcpdump` on a node which I can see many outbound TCP connections to a specific host (inside my network) on a specific port (8086).  I'd like to know which process is making those connections.

I used:

```
while true; do ss -ntap '{ dport :8086 }'; sleep 0.1; done
```

however, I don't see anything show up even when tcpdump captured outgoing requests to that port.

I tried using auditd to capture them at the kernel level, as I thought `ss` may not be capturing these *small* requests.

I used: `auditctl -A exit,always  -F arch=x86_64 -S connect -S sendmsg -S sendto -k send` and used `ausearch -k send -i` to look for these requests, but again, no avail.

I'm wondering how could it possible that TCP connections are made to an external host while not captured by auditd?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The original destination address and destination port can be other, not `tcp/8086`, but with `DNAT` iptables rule in `nat/OUTPUT` it is rewritten to other address and other port. In the `tcpdump` capture you see packets after iptables translation.
2. It can be kernel module, not userspace application. In this case I'm not sure, what `auditd` can show anything.
3. It also can be raw socket, when packets are constructed in application. I think in this case you can list raw sockets with `ss --raw` command.
4. It can be other network namespace, not main.
5. This traffic can be forwarded, not local-originated. In this case `ss` and `auditd` show nothing.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  I have more leads to look at.  Thanks a bunch!